# Control de cambios en Overleaf

Tags: latex

Estoy intentando hacer un control de cambios en LaTeX (lo tengo en Overleaf) como se hace en Word, he intentado con el paquete *latexdiff*, pero no he podido tener los resultados esperados.
La estructura de mi proyecto en LaTeX es así:

1. **Tesis.tex** (es el archivo principal donde se encuentran los paquetes)
2. Int.tex
3. Cap1.tex
4. Cap2.tex
5. ...
6. Bibl.tex

No obstante, el paquete *latexdiff* solo compara dos archivos de la siguiente forma *latexdiff draft.tex revision.tex > diff.tex*.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda respecto al tema.

Gracias

P.D.: Busco algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Fue útil la respuesta? Comenta si necesitas más :)

Answer (score 0):

Sé de algunas alternativas para hacer esto además de `latexdiff`, pero nunca he usado ninguna de ellas.

1. [**TrackChanges**](http://trackchanges.sourceforge.net/web_preview.html) parece un proyecto externo;
2. [`todonotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes) está disponible en [CTAN](https://ctan.org/) y se considera el más similar al estilo de MS Word (esta opción estaría bien en Overleaf);
3. [`changes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/changes) está también disponible en [CTAN](https://ctan.org/);
4. cito para completar [**TextCompare**](https://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=screenshot&shot=TextCompare), que hace lo mismo, pero en el código.

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)